# Hyper realism in sound design approach

Tags: hyper-realism, recommendations, sound-design, movies

Hi everyone.

I was wondering if any of you guys had the chance to go through any type of work involving a hyper-realistic approach. I'm doing my Honours Project on a film that requires that sort of approach and it would be helpful to read and/or check other movies that have something to do with the likes of Jan Svankmajer or Tim Burton.

Thanks in advance and keep up the good work.

Marco

Comment: "Hyper-realistic" could be interpreted a lot of ways, especially with the two examples you put forth. Can you narrow down what you're looking for, or add some specificity?

Comment: Hi Shaun

I would consider hyperrealism the exaggeration of the sound design to make it look different, never reaching surrealism. If you take a look at the film "Alice" directed by Jan Svankmajer in the 80's you will hear sounds that are presented from a very close distance, as if the audience could almost feel them. The thing is it is not easy to find other types of examples out there.

Answer (score 1):

One filmic example that comes to mind is the repetitive sequence used to visually abstract the scenes of dosing in Aronofsky's "Requiem for a Dream." Not sure if that's closer to the idea you're aiming for.

*Note: I'm not sure I'd have called out Svankmajer's sound as purposeful, and would have chocked it up to budgetary or technical reasons, but upon reflection, 100% of his films do have that quality, even later ones like Otasanek. At the same time, I hear a lot of that overly-dry-and-too-hot sound design in independent animations of many stripes. Hm. Interesting perspective, though, thanks for spinning up a thread on it.*

Answer (score 0):

The scene in the Godfather where he has to kill the bloke in the restaurant is probably the most famous example of hyper realistic sound in cinema.

Comment: Hi Noiseboy

Do you mean the scene where Michael kills Solozzo? I would consider the sound of his twisted thoughts as something more surrealistic than hyper-real. The guys are having dinner at the restaurant, and hyperrealism would be us hearing how they chew or how they interact with any object that is obvious to the camera.

Comment: Yes I am talking about that scene; but hyper realistic in the sense that the passing subway train is over amplified to echo his nervousness in performing the kill, certainly a hyper realistic use of the surrounding environment of the restaurant.